# Describing $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R (R/J, R/J )$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

> Let $J$ be an ideal of  a commutative ring with unity $R$. Is it true that $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R (R/J, R/J ) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(J/J^2, R/J)$ ?

Since $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R (R/J, R/J) \cong J/J^2$, equivalently I'm asking whether $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R (R/J, R/J ) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(\mathrm{Tor}_1^R (R/J, R/J), R/J)$ ?

I tried using the short exact sequence $0 \to J/J^2 \to R/J^2 \to R/J \to 0$ to get a long exact sequence of $\mathrm{Ext}$'s, but got no where.

Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373225/description-of-mathrmext1r-i-r-j

Comment: @user26857: but the linked post doesn't have any proof of the fact ...

Comment: From the first comment under the question we get $\mathrm{Ext}^1(R/J,R/J)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(J,R/J)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} \DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}$
Yes, this is true.  From the short exact sequence $$0\to J\to R\to R/J\to 0$$ we get a long exact sequence $$\Hom(R,R/J)\to \Hom(J,R/J)\to \Ext^1(R/J,R/J)\to \Ext^1(R,R/J)=0.$$ Now note that for any $R$-module $M$, any homomorphism $M\to R/J$ vanishes on $JM$.  Applying this to $M=R$, we see that the map $$\Hom(R,R/J)\to \Hom(J,R/J)$$ in our sequence above is $0$, so that the map $$\Hom(J,R/J)\to \Ext^1(R/J,R/J)$$ is an isomorphism by exactness.  Applying the remark above with $M=J$ now tells us that $\Hom(J,R/J)\cong \Hom(J/J^2,R/J)$, and so we have the desired isomorphism $$\Hom(J/J^2,R/J)\cong\Ext^1(R/J,R/J).$$

Comment: Remark. The above proof of the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(J, R/J) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(R/J, R/J)$ does not require $R$ to be commutative.

Comment: @Orat: That's not true.  The map $\operatorname{Hom}(R,R/J)\to \operatorname{Hom}(J,R/J)$ may be nonzero if $R$ is noncommutative, since $R/J$ may not be annihilated by $J$ as a left module.  For instance, if $R=M_n(k)$ for a field $k$ and some $n>1$, then $R$ as a left module over itself is isomorphic to $V^n$ where $V=k^n$ with the canonical action of $R$.  Taking $J$ to be one of the copies of $V$ in $V^n$, then $J$ is a direct summand of $R$ so every homomorphism $J\to R/J$ extends to $R$, but there are plenty of nonzero homomorphisms $J\to R/J$ since $J\cong V$ and $R/J\cong V^{n-1}$.

Comment: In that example, the Ext is trivial since $R$ is semisimple, but $\operatorname{Hom}(J,R/J)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: My comment was totally wrong. Obviously not true for semisimple cases like that. Thank you for your correction!